# Get the first node value from xml in sql column using powershell

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell

I am trying get the first node value from the xml stored in the sql column. Currently it is displayed all the UniqueID but i want only first one i.e +7f8wMRJgFKWlQqyWwI27yOVc80=

**XML** :

```
<UniqueIDList>
    <UniqueID>+7f8wMRJgFKWlQqyWwI27yOVc80=</UniqueID>
    <UniqueID>3LZYc365TRSHEUZRwBaaYCPszqQ=</UniqueID>
    <UniqueID>WnK4aLZKO8kFyi+Ii8s9A2yl/Kg=</UniqueID>
    <UniqueID>i0UHoU0r2fYBvCrvFbcKkikXgas=</UniqueID>
</UniqueIDList>
```

**Powershell Code** :

```
$connectionString = "Server=tcp:$dataSource.database.windows.net,1433;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"

$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$con.Open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = "select license from tbllicense order by LicenseID desc"
$cmd.Connection = $con

$as = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$as.SelectCommand = $cmd
$as.Fill($ds);

$xmlDocs = $ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
write-host "License Value : " $xmlDocs
Select-Xml -Content $xmlDocs -XPath "//UniqueID" | foreach {write-host $_.node.InnerXML}
```

Comment: Something like this maybe?
`(Select-Xml -Content $xmlDocs -XPath "//UniqueID")[0].Node.InnerXml`

Comment: thanks it works. :)